# How to set the pandas display width to be the same as the notebook's output width?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

Pandas is wrapping printed dataframes less than halfway through the width of the cell in Google colab notebook.

I already tried `pandas.options.display.width = 0` (which I read would cause pandas to autodetect display width) but that didn't change the behaviour.

How can I make pandas not wrap the tables unless it actually has to, based on how wide the notebook is?